# Eclipse removes -nosuperDevMode parameter in running configuration

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse, gwt-super-dev-mode, gwt-dev-mode

I'm using eclipse and GWT 2.8. From GWT 2.8 in running configuration in eclipse it removes -nosuperDevMode after every restart. It is annoying because I want to debug client code in eclipse, not in browser. Can it be fixed somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm still Google plugin 2.7 but this would be annoying me too. Have you got a working solution? Btw. I don't see Google GWT 2.8 plugin is available for update in Eclipse yet, how did you update it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before.
I found that I need to update the GWT plugin for eclipse from the GWT site
http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/Download.html

It will delete the old plugin, and you will have to add a facet gwt to your project, but the classic dev mode is working without workaround

If you don't want to update your plugin, as a workaround in eclipse, you can set the run configuration to be kept in a file in your projet (Run configuration / your gwt webapp / common tab / Save as : shared file / store it in .settings for exemple)

When you have done this, configure it whith the -nosuperDevMode parameter, then go to the .settings directory with your file explorer and set the run file (xxx.launch) read only.

Eclipse cannot override it again, it will warn when you open the configuration but it is working.